# Sentry.io сделать рассылку на дополнительные emails

Tags: php, laravel

Моё приложение написано на laravel и использует sentry.io для отлова ошибок . Надо сделать так что бы сообщения которые отправляет sentry на почту , отправлялись ещё и на доп . емайлы которые задаются в админ панели моего приложения

Comment: Все просто, нужно добавить поля в админки которые будут добавлять email адреса к email-у sentry.io пробуйте, удачи!

Comment: А можно поподробнее как редактировать конфиг sentry из моего приложения ?